# Control a solenoid with NFC

Tags: microcontrollers, nfc

I am trying to determine the components I may need to use an NFC sensor to control a solenoid. The amount of space I have to work with is very small -
 approximately 1 inch. The solenoid I have in mind is less than 1/2" long and can be viewed here - http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/191921105068?chn=ps&dispItem=1

To clarify the problem I am trying to solve. The idea is to have a smart phone app control this entire process and to record all actions. Trying to create a "smart" personal device. The solenoid would serve to "flip a switch" on the device. Again, I have very limited space. I want the required close proximity of the NFC as a security feature to turn on the personal device. The process would be to open the app, key in a PIN, touch phone to device to turn on, touch phone to device to turn off.

The specific questions are:

1. Which very small NFC sensor could best service the purpose of communicating with a smart phone and somehow sending the signal to the solenoid?
2. Would I need a micro-controller to make the NFC send the signal to the solenoid? Is so, which very small controller would meet this need?
3. Am I missing anything else? I know I need a battery source.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense as a design choice.  NFC chips are miniscule and there are both tiny MCUs and those with build in NFC, though the antenna coil takes some space on the order of your limit.  But the range is also short - nearly *in contact*.  You probably want a different technology for this,or at least to explain what you are trying to *accomplish* rather than how you are trying to do it.

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment, what is the end goal here? Also as this question stands it probably should be on https://electronics.stackexchange.com as I'm struggling to see where the internet part is

Comment: To clarify the problem I am trying to solve. The idea is to have a smart phone app control this entire process and to record all actions. Trying to create a "smart" personal device. The solenoid would serve to "flip a switch" on the device. Again, I have very limited space. I want the required close proximity of the NFC as a security feature to turn on the personal device. The process would be to open the app, key in a PIN,  touch phone to device to turn on, touch phone to device to turn off.

Comment: This is really too deep into electronic implementation to be a fit here - pick an NFC chip and a small MCU, or an integrated NFC and MCU, add an NFET and a power source.  Experiment with antennas around the perimeter of your device until you find something that works.  Depending on how many you plan to make, optimize for ease of development, or production cost.  Ideally you find something that can wake up from a fully off state when the NFC couples enough energy to trigger it, though you solenoid will require  battery.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let presume that you want to send info/input/command to the solenoid via smart phone with enabled NFC. In that case you need NFC reader to establish communication with NFC enabled smart phone. 
   NFC sensor/reader can be found on amazon.com or on alibaba.com, let say device as you can find on [this link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/13-56Mhz-Rfid-Reader-NFC-Contactless_60681614687.html?spm=a2).
2. NFC reader should transmit data to the MCU/IoT Board/PC/Raspberry Pi/Arduino so you can process input data and make decision what you want to do with solenoid activate/deactivate.
   Cost-effective solution for board capable to do this job can be **TopDuino** [found on link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Best-Sale-TopDuino-Uno-Control-Board_60604397796.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.9.3c93b095CJzmNJ&s=p).
3. In order to issue command to the solenoid I suggest to use RELAY device. **[SugerCube](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Suger-cube-JQC-3F-10A-12VDC_1322346491.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.69.3c93b095DQahek&s=p)** can do this job.
4. So, most probably you will need architecture like bellow:

   ```
   NFC<-->IoT.Controller<-->Actuator<-->Solenoid
   ```